# How join Sometable with self

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need join Sometable with self. With sql it's easy, but how to write it on activerecord?

```
select
  t1.text,
  t2.text
from sometable t1, (select
                     text
                   from sometable
                   where text = 'home') t2
where t1.id in (t2.some_id);
```

Comment: self.joins(:some_table)

Comment: ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError (Can't join 'Sometable' to association named 'sometable'; perhaps you misspelled it?)

Answer (score 1):

It's a self-join in Rails. Rails' document: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins